# Advise to improve Query Performance (Oracle)

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g

I have a table (A) with 116,317,979 records and it is growing everyday by around 750,000 records per day.

As per my requirement I want to efficiently fetch last 3 complete days data from the table using a date column (date-time is stored in the column). So the query will be

```
select * from A where date_column >= trunc(sysdate) - 3
```

I also need to join the table A with table B such that

```
select * from A 
left outer join B 
on A.X = B.X and A.Y = B.Y and A.Z = B.Z and B.M = 'XYZ' and B.N = 'UIM'
where A.date_column >= trunc(sysdate) - 3
```

> Unique Index & PK of Table B (X,Y,Z,M,N)
>
> Unique Index & PK of Table A (ID)

---

> Proposed IDX 1 on Table A (date_column)
>
> Proposed IDX 2 on Table A (X,Y,Z)

```
Time without Indexes 34 sec
Time with IDX 1      32 sec
Time with IDX 1 & 2  27 sec //Sorry about the mistype
```

By only adding an index on A.date_column I thought I could significantly increase the performance but my tests results are negative. Are there any other hints with which i can increase the performance apart from adding new indexes? Is there any harm in adding indexes like these in the long run.

**OR**

It is better to create another table and populate last 3 days data in it somehow live(using db trigger). I can easily have another process to purge data older than 3 days every night.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle partitioning would make sense here, but this is an extra cost option even for Enterprise Edition.
In case partitioning is not available - the separate table keeping last 3 days should be the best for performance. You should try it.

If you want to get maximum from indexes then you can consider to play a bit with the physical parameters:

- if date column is not updated and the data is rarely deleted then you can set `PCTFREE 0`
- looking at your final query, I would suggest to create an index on trunc(date) column and use compression -> in this case each index data block store much more entries. In this case the final query condition should be `trunc(date_column) >= trunc(sysdate) - 3`

Depending on the selectivity of X,Y,Z in table A, it could make sense to compress them as well. So I suggest to check two cases:

1. `create index trunc_date_ai on A(trunc(date_column)) pctfree 0 compress;` + your IDX2
2. `create index trunc_date_ai on A(trunc(date_column),X,Y,Z) pctfree 0 compress;`
   `pctfree 0` should be used in case X,Y,Z are not updated in table A.
   `compress` keyword here makes compression for all 4 columns, so it is worth using if X,Y,Z values are highly repeatable in table A for particular trunc(date_column).

To force the index usage you can hint the query, for example like this:

```
select --+ index (A trunc_date_ai)
       * 
from   A left outer join B 
on A.X = B.X and A.Y = B.Y and A.Z = B.Z and B.M = 'XYZ' and B.N = 'UIM'
where trunc(A.date_column) >= trunc(sysdate) - 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did some tests and found out that suggested cases 1 & 2 have close to similar performance and the difference is not that much. I also didn't use the `pctfree 0` option. Adding compress dramatically reduced the size of the index `(trunc(date),x,y,z)` in storage from `4.349gb` to `1.438`gb. As we have almost 750000 records added in a day, trunc(date) is repeated multiple times & even x,y,z is highly repetative. Is there any side effect of using compress in this scenario ?

Comment: I have another similar environment with almost 10 times less data than this & the performance of having a separate table with only 3 days data will be much better however I am worried about added an overhead with trigger insert. Trigger will look something like `if date > sysdate - 3 then insert into new_table`. Having this statement run 750000 times a day is scary and it will completely eliminate the performance gain I am getting because of batch inserts IMO. However I might be very wrong in this case. Can you advice ?

Comment: Also currently my index script shows `Compress 4`, how does oracle determine the value 4?

Comment: Side effect is the performance of data changes (dml). So it's better to estimate this effect. Re the trigger - I don't think it makes sense to impement the trigger on insert. Since you insert the data in regular batches - then I suggest to refresh small table as a separate procedure run after each batch insert. To make this refresh faster and in case date column is not changed, then you can simply save the last processed Id value of table A and next time process the records in A where id > _saved_id_from_last_refresh_run_. Of course, you need to clean up old data once per day. Hope that helps.

Comment: Compress 4 is expected. If you don't specify the compression degree in create index statement then all the index columns are compressed.

Comment: As long as the DML effect is not huge, it will be fine for us as we are only inserting records every few minutes in batches. Updates happen rarely & deletes occur very rarely.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the execution plan to see if the indexes are being used.  I am guessing that the index on `date_column` is not used and the difference between 32 and 34 seconds is just noise.

I would suggest an index on `A(date_column, X, Y, Z)` for this query.

Is there harm to adding indexes?  Well, they add overhead on `insert`s/`update`s/`delete`s.  If your inserts are transactional, then you are inserting about 10 rows per second -- not counting updates and deletes.  If your peaks are significantly higher than that *and* your hardware is not very good, then the indexes could slow things down.  If the additional rows are added in batches, I wouldn't worry about the overhead.

I doubt that splitting the table out into a separate 3-day table would make much of a difference.  But why listen to me?  Try it out.  Take the last 3+ days of data, dump it into a table, index it properly and see if the queries are faster.

Comment: My inserts are happening in batches but it happens almost 6 times every 15 mins.

Comment: @pOrinG . . . I wouldn't worry so much about the index overhead if the inserts are happening less than once a minute.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain little bit more about the overhead. You are saying that as the inserts are happening frequently the overhead will be insignificant right ?. If the inserts would be happening in huge batches then it would be a bigger problem?

Comment: @pOrinG . . . I would be worried about locking contention among multiple queries.  My guess is that updating the indexes on a few rows might take a second or two.  That is not much of a threat every 15 minutes or so -- and they are not going to interfere with each other.  If you are doing the inserts multiple times per second, then they might interfere with each other and with other queries.  Of course, if your batches are 1,000,000 rows, then the locking would take longer and might be a bigger issue.